# What is difference between "owned pointer" and the "stored pointer" for std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

As per this documentation, which says (emphasis mine):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/owner_before/

> Unlike the operator< overload, this ordering takes into consideration the **shared_ptr's owned pointer**, and not **the stored pointer** in such a way that two of these objects are considered equivalent (i.e., this function returns false no matter the order of the operands) if they both share ownership, or they are both empty, even if their stored pointer value are different.
>
> The **stored pointer** (i.e., the pointer the shared_ptr object dereferences to) may not be **the owned pointer** (i.e., the pointer deleted on object destruction) if the shared_ptr object is an alias (alias-constructed objects and their copies).

What is the difference between "owned pointer" and the "stored pointer" of `std::shared_ptr`?

I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

Here is some related code (check http://cpp.sh/27auqq):

```
// enable_shared_from_this example
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct C : std::enable_shared_from_this<C> {int a; int b; };

int main () {
  std::shared_ptr<C> foo, bar;

  foo = std::make_shared<C>();

  bar = foo->shared_from_this();
  
  std::shared_ptr<int> p1(foo, &foo->a);
  std::shared_ptr<int> p2(foo, &foo->b);
  
  *p1=5;
  *p2=9;
  
  std::cout << p1.use_count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo->a << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo->b << std::endl;

  if (!foo.owner_before(bar) && !bar.owner_before(foo))
    std::cout << "foo and bar share ownership" << std::endl;
    
  if(!p1.owner_before(p2) && !p2.owner_before(p1))
    std::cout << "p1 and p2 share ownership" << std::endl;
    
    if(!p1.owner_before(foo) && !foo.owner_before(p1))
    std::cout << "p1 and foo share ownership" << std::endl;
      

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
4
5
9
foo and bar share ownership
p1 and p2 share ownership
p1 and foo share ownership
```

Comment: That site is not a good reference. Despite its name, it is not official, It is written by enthusiasts, often confusing, and sometimes wrong. The only reason it stays on top of Google's results is that it's at the top of Google's results, constantly reinforcing its "relevance". [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/owner_before) is better.

Comment: And the question is...? Also, show the output of your program, not just a link off-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support things like converting a `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base>` even when no virtual destructor exists (which is allowed in that case even if it isn't a great idea in general for dynamically allocated classes), and for a few other features, `shared_ptr` needs to have one pointer to the object designated by each specific instance in that instance, and another one in the control block. The control block is used:

- for counting "strong references" (owners of the dynamically allocated used ressource managed by the `shared_ptr`) and "weak references" (owners of the control block but not of the managed used resource);
- to remember what to delete (pointer to the owned object) and how to delete it. **The control block holds the exact pointer value that was passed to the original `shared_ptr` constructor**.

Usually that value is used only for the purpose of deletion. Its value is examined (compared) only when you use `owner_before`. *All other functions examine the pointer in each `shared_ptr` instance, not the pointer in the control block.*

Comment: Quote from your answer[emphasis mine]: "**In order to support things like converting a shared_ptr<Derived> to shared_ptr<Base> even when no virtual destructor exists** (which is allowed in that case even if **it isn't a great idea in general for dynamically allocated classes)**". Do you implicit the function `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`?  And why isn't it a great idea in general for dynamically allocated classes? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: Almost all classes that you intent to use as base classes, and that aren't solely used as an automatic or global or member objects, *should have a virtual dtor.* 1) If you have even one other virtual function, the compiler will make a vtable for each class (that one and the derived ones) and (at least) one vptr in each instance, so the cost is already there. 2) **The virtual dtor is used when deleting a derived instance via a ptr to a base.**  So almost all classes that have one virtual function should also have a virtual dtor; it's very basic advice - but not hard rule.

Comment: You can sometimes get away with not having a virtual dtor even for a class `B` that is the base of `D`, even w/ dynamic allocation and deallocation: when you ensure that **you only ever apply the `delete` operator to the pointer value of type `D*` returned by `new D`, NOT to that value converted to type `B*`.** Since derived to base pointer conversions are a very commonly used tool in C++, an implicit conversion (and a non controversial one), not doing the conversion or not used the converted value for deallocation isn't intuitive. So don't try it and have a virtual dtor in `B`.

Comment: If you still do not want a virtual dtor in `B` for some reason, you can use `shared_ptr` to manage dynamically allocated objects. If you only create dynamically allocated objects of type `D` either by `make_shared<D>(...)` or `shared_ptr<D>(new D(...))` then you are fine, as the smart ptr **will never do a derived to base ptr conversion before using `delete`**; IOW even after conversion to `shared_ptr<B>`, a ptr value of type `D*` will be the argument to `delete` when the last owner (last sharing `shared_ptr`) is destroyed. [So my point has nothing to do w/ `dynamic_pointer_cast`.]

Comment: Thank you for that very clear explanation. I have a greater understanding of it with your help. I carefully studied your reply and did some tests(see godbolt.org/z/cVBSwU). A question arises, **how does it achieve** (i.e. even after conversion to shared_ptr<B>, **a ptr value of type D* will be the argument to delete** when the last owner is destroyed even when **no virtual destructor existing in the base class**)? I fully understand and approve of your saying that the virtual dtor is used when deleting a derived instance via a ptr to a base(i.e **the virtual dtor is needed here**.).

Answer (score 6):

> What is the difference between "owned pointer" and the "stored pointer" for `std::shared_ptr`?

Anytime you use the constructor `template< class Y > shared_ptr::shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;`, you have something that shares ownership with `r`, but dereferences to `*ptr`.

E.g. after

```
std::shared_ptr<std::pair<int, double>> pair = std::make_shared<std::pair<int,double>>(1, 2.);
std::shared_ptr<int> i(pair, &pair->first);
pair.reset();
```

the `std::pair<int, double>` is kept alive by `i`

Comment: One more question, I wonder why `pair.use_count` returns `0` whereas the pair is kept alive by `i`.You check it on https://godbolt.org/z/iVdw77.

Comment: @John because `pair` no longer owns anything

Comment: `i.use_count()` is 1

Comment: I see. I comprehend it on a deeper level with your help. Thank you.